# My JQuery CSS menu fails to hide

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a simple jQuery Menu that expands on hover however unless the user hovers over another menu item or clicks else where in the page, the menu items do not get hidden. When you load another page using the links on the menu the page opens and leaves the menu expanded. How can I fix this? A fiddle with all the html and css can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/njueukavi/GJkP5/). My jQuery code is here

```
                $(document).ready(function(){

                    $("#header_nav > li ").addClass("level1");
                    $("#header_nav  > li > ul > li ").addClass("level2");
                    $("#header_nav  > li > ul > li > ul > li ").addClass("level3");

                    $(".level1").live("hover",function(){

                        $(".level1").removeClass("main_menu_hover");
                        $(this).addClass("main_menu_hover");


                        var numberofChildren = $(this).find("> ul").children().length;

                        if(numberofChildren != 0){
                            // Section 1
                            $(".level1").removeClass("active_main_menu");
                            $(this).addClass("active_main_menu");

                            // Section 2
                            $(".level1").find("ul").css("display","none");
                            $(this).find(" > ul").css("display","block");

                            // Section 3
                            $(".level2").removeClass("active_first_element");
                            $(".level2").removeClass("active_last_element");
                            $(".level2").removeClass("active_only_element");

                            // Section 4
                            if(numberofChildren == 1){
                                $(this).find("ul li:first").addClass("active_only_element");
                            }else{
                                $(this).find("ul li:first").addClass("active_first_element");
                                $(this).find("ul li:last-child").addClass("active_last_element");
                            }

                            // Section 5
                            $(".level2 a").removeClass("sub_active");
                            $(".level2").removeClass("menu_hover");


                        }else{
                            // Section 6
                            $(".level1").find("ul").css("display","none");
                            $(".level1").removeClass("active_main_menu");

                        }

                    });

                    $(".level2").find(".arrow-right").attr("href","javascript:void(0);");

                    $(".level2 > a").live("hover",function(e){
                        $("li").removeClass("menu_hover");
                        $(this).parent().addClass("menu_hover");
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });

                    $(".level2 a").live("click",function(){
                        $("li").removeClass("menu_hover");

                        if($(this).hasClass("sub_active")){
                            $(this).removeClass("sub_active");
                            $(".level2 > ul").slideUp();
                        }else{
                            $(".level2 ul").slideUp();
                            $(".level2 a").removeClass("sub_active");
                            $(this).addClass("sub_active");
                            $(this).parent().find("ul").slideDown();
                        }
                    });





                    $(".level3 a").live("hover",function(){
                        if(!($(this).parent().hasClass("accordian_element_hover"))){
                            $(this).parent().removeClass("level3").addClass("accordian_element_hover");
                        }
                    });
                    $(".accordian_element_hover a").live("hover",function(){
                        $(this).parent().addClass("level3").removeClass("accordian_element_hover");
                    });


                });
```

Comment: is there any reason why you're using live? if you just use .hover(), you can just hide it on the out callback: .hover(hoverInCallback,hoverOutCallback);

Comment: I think if menu code generate from ajax or append after html render, the 'hover' method may be not working

Comment: @kennypu I'm new to jquery and tried it with hover and it didn't work as expected. Tran the menu code is not generated from ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$(".level1").live("mouseover mouseout", function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
            //Your old menu code
    } else {
        $(this).attr("class","level1");
        $(this).find("ul").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should hide all menus when a link is clicked:

```
$('#mainmenucontainer a').click(function(){
    $(".level1").find("ul").css("display", "none");
    $(".level1").removeClass("active_main_menu");
});
```